# Рамка вокруг "carousel-items" в Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, html5, веб-программирование

В данном коде реализуется карусель. Но никак правильно не получается отобразить рамку с padding.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<div class="row places" v-show="cafedral">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                                        <h5>Кафедральный собор(архитектура, история, искусство)<a href="https://2gis.ru/kaliningrad/firm/5630027815206179" class="nav_a2"><img src="images/2gis.png" alt="" height="15px" width="35px" style="margin-left: 1px;"></a></h5>
                                    </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
                                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                              <div class="carousel-item active ">
                                                <img src="images/test.jpg" class="d-block img_dost img_dost_border " alt="...">
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="carousel-item ">
                                                <img src="images/kafedralnyj-sobor_2.jpg" class="d-block img_dost img_dost_border" alt="...">
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="carousel-item ">
                                                <img src="images/kafedralnyj-sobor_3.jpg" class="d-block img_dost img_dost_border" alt="...">
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                                    <img src="images/left-arrow.svg" width="30px">
                                                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                            </span>
                                                  <span class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="" data-slide="next">
                                                    <img src="images/arrow-point-to-right.svg" width="30px">
                                                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                                  </span>
                                          </div>
                            </div>
                                  

                                                                
                            <div class="col-sm-6 text_dost2">
                                    Кафедральный собор – это один из символов Калининграда. Возраст сооружения насчитывает около 700 лет (с 1333 года). Сейчас собор используется как музей, где можно детально изучить историю Кенигсберга. Обязательно узнайте о графике органных концертов – все посетившие туристы очень хорошо отзываются и выражают полнейший восторг. Цена посещения: 250 рублей для взрослого, 150 рублей органный концерт. Рядом с Кафедральным собором начинаются экскурсии на катерах по реке Преголя.
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

```
.img_dost_border{
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
        padding: 5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поэксперементируйте с margin 
Если не поможет просто сдвиньте картинку чуть левее. Правый тест имеет z-индекс больше чем картинка, поэтому части рамки просто не видно